# Typescript Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type error

Tags: typescript

I am getting several errors related to `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type`. Some of the things I have tried doing are: 
a. deleting node_modules folder and reinstalling it using the `yarn` command.

eg: for the first `Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'` issue, I have the same require variable declared in

**\src\Nucleus.Web.Vue\node_modules@types\node\globals.d.ts**

```
declare var require: NodeJS.Require;
```

**\src\Nucleus.Web.Vue\node_modules@types\webpack-env\index.d.ts**

```
declare var require: NodeRequire;
```

What am I missing and how could I workaround this issue?

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "nucleus-web-vue",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.5.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^13.1.1",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.2",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "sass": "^1.24.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.4.3"
  }
}
```

**Error log:**

```
  ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(167,13):
    167:13 Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'Require'.
        165 | declare function queueMicrotask(callback: () => void): void;
        166 |
      > 167 | declare var require: NodeJS.Require;
            |             ^
        168 | declare var module: NodeJS.Module;
        169 |
        170 | // Same as module.exports
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(168,13):
    168:13 Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'module' must be of type 'NodeModule', but here has type 'Module'.
        166 |
        167 | declare var require: NodeJS.Require;
      > 168 | declare var module: NodeJS.Module;
            |             ^
        169 |
        170 | // Same as module.exports
        171 | declare var exports: any;
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(279,11):
    279:11 Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'RequireFunction' and 'Require'.
      Named property 'cache' of types 'RequireFunction' and 'Require' are not identical.
        277 | }
        278 |
      > 279 | interface NodeRequire extends __WebpackModuleApi.RequireFunction {
            |           ^
        280 | }
        281 |
        282 | declare var require: NodeRequire;
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(279,11):
    279:11 Interface 'NodeRequire' cannot simultaneously extend types 'RequireFunction' and 'Require'.
      Named property 'resolve' of types 'RequireFunction' and 'Require' are not identical.
        277 | }
        278 |
      > 279 | interface NodeRequire extends __WebpackModuleApi.RequireFunction {
            |           ^
        280 | }
        281 |
        282 | declare var require: NodeRequire;
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(331,11):
    331:11 Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'Module'.
      Named property 'children' of types 'Module' and 'Module' are not identical.
        329 | declare var DEBUG: boolean;
        330 |
      > 331 | interface NodeModule extends __WebpackModuleApi.Module {}
            |           ^
        332 |
        333 | declare var module: NodeModule;
        334 |
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(331,11):
    331:11 Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'Module'.
      Named property 'parent' of types 'Module' and 'Module' are not identical.
        329 | declare var DEBUG: boolean;
        330 |
      > 331 | interface NodeModule extends __WebpackModuleApi.Module {}
            |           ^
        332 |
        333 | declare var module: NodeModule;
        334 |
    ERROR in /src/Nucleus.Web.Vue/node_modules/@types/webpack-env/index.d.ts(331,11):
    331:11 Interface 'NodeModule' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Module' and 'Module'.
      Named property 'require' of types 'Module' and 'Module' are not identical.
        329 | declare var DEBUG: boolean;
        330 |
      > 331 | interface NodeModule extends __WebpackModuleApi.Module {}
            |           ^
        332 |
        333 | declare var module: NodeModule;
        334 |
```

**tsconfig.json;**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "vuetify",
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
    "src/shared/application"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I mean, `declare var require: any;` would resolve this but dirty and you lose intellisense.

Comment: Thanks @zze for your input. My question was more around how do we fix this "from the root"? I really don't want to fiddle around node_modules source code when it will be overwritten with an npm update. I also see these kinds of issues all over the web but no concrete fix "from the root" solution.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, didn't see that those imports were within nodules.